# Customizing Spatie Laravel-Permission Exception Message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I have added the [Saptie Laravel Permission Package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) in a Laravel 5.8 API application. Every works fine and I get exception when a non admin user tries to access admin specific routes.

However the default exception is rendered as HTML `403 User does not have the right roles`. Considering I am using this inside an API application, I would like to return my own custom message for such exceptions.

I tried checking if the `auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')` but still got the same default exception page. Here's my code

route

```
Route::post('products', 'ProductController@store')->middleware('role:super-admin|admin'); // create a new product
```

Controller method

```
if (auth()->user()->hasRole('admin')) {

    // create & store the product
    $product = Product::create($request->all())

    // return new product
    $responseMessage    = 'Successful operation';
    $responseStatus     = 200;
    $productResource    = new ProductResource($product);

    return response()->json([
        'responseMessage'   => $responseMessage,
        'responseStatus'    => $responseStatus,
        'product'           => $productResource
    ]);
} else {

    return response()->json([
        'responseMessage'   => 'You do not have required authorization.',
        'responseStatus'    => 403,
    ]);
}
```

Why is my custom message not showing?

Comment: The code you posted does not throw a `UnauthorizedException`, did you protect your routes through the middleware e.g. `role:admin`? If yes then your controller is never reached so your code is never run.

Comment: @Remul yes I am calling the `role:admin` middleware on the route. See edited post for the route. If the user role is being checked before the controller is hit, then what do I do to return json response instead of rendering html 403 page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you are protecting your routes through the `role` middleware the `UnauthorizedException` will be thrown before your controller code is ever reached.

What you can do is use laravels exception handler `render` method and check the exception type and return your own response:

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#render-method):

> The render method is responsible for converting a given exception into
>   an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser. By default,
>   the exception is passed to the base class which generates a response
>   for you. However, you are free to check the exception type or return
>   your own custom response

**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
        return response()->json([
            'responseMessage' => 'You do not have required authorization.',
            'responseStatus'  => 403,
        ]);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: I added your code to the `render` method of *app/Exceptions/Handler.php* but still got the default exception page.

Comment: Did you import `UnauthorizedException`? e.g. `use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;`

Comment: This has now been added to the [documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/advanced-usage/exceptions/), thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 10 it's slightly different, I used @Remul's answer as a basis:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;
use Spatie\Permission\Exceptions\UnauthorizedException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * The list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });

        $this->renderable(function (UnauthorizedException $e, Request $request) {
            if ($request->is('api/*')) {
                return response()->json([
                    'responseMessage' => 'You do not have required authorization.',
                    'responseStatus'  => 403,
                ], 403);
            }
        });
    }
}
```